# Infinitive phrase

Tags: grammar

I have been puzzling my head over the infinitive usage in the sentence:

> The girl who is going to be interviewed tomorrow does not speak English.

So, may I replace "who is going to be interviewed" just with "to be interviewed"?

> The girl to be interviewed tomorrow does not speak English.

And what say about this other variant?

> The girl being interviewed tomorrow does not speak English.

Could you please comment on each variant given and specify if the meaning in the first sentence remains the same in the two others?

Comment: Your two variants have the same meaning and all are equally acceptable.

Comment: By the way, there is no infinitive verb in that sentence. There's the phrase *be going to* in the present tense, "The girl who is going to", and the passive form of *interview*, "be interviewed."

Comment: But, what about the second and the third sentences. Are they grammatically correct?